# How to display four li tag in one row with equal height?

Tags: html, css

I have an item list which is coming dynamically from the database so I don't have any idea about the content. I have to display the four li in a single row with equal height. I tried below code but it's not working.

I tried `display:flex` to the `ul` but all the li tags are displaying in one line. I also try `display: table` and `display: table-cell;` but the same issue all are displaying in one line.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.List {
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: auto;
}

.List ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.List ul li {
  width: 24%;
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 12px 0px #EBE8E8;
  border-radius: 03px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: auto 07px 14px auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="List">
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo sociis natoque
    </li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean </li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque
    </li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo sociis natoque
    </li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean </li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo sociis natoque
    </li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque
    </li>


  </ul>
</div>
```

```
My expected output is 


1  2  3  4
5  6
```

Comment: except 'display: flex', try also adding 'flex-direction: row' to the ul, see if that works

Comment: @Kenny, Nope It's not working.

Comment: Hi, I just put it on JS Fiddle, please see if this help.https://jsfiddle.net/KennyChoy/e9obLarh/4/

Comment: @Kenny, Try to add more than 4 li tags. In your jsfiddle,  If you add more then 4 li then all will display in one line.

Comment: then just apply flex-wrap: wrap; have updated the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/KennyChoy/e9obLarh/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've put together a sample for you, let's check it out:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.List {
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: auto;
}

.List ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.List ul li {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 12px 0px #EBE8E8;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="List">
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo sociis natoque
    </li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean </li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque
    </li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo sociis natoque
    </li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean </li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo sociis natoque
    </li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque
    </li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo sociis natoque
    </li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Let's break it down a bit so you can understand it more clearly.

First, we reset the `box-sizing` property with this:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This ensures that the column width won't be affected by `border-width` and `padding` properties, which you are using with `padding: 20px;`

By default, using `display: flex` will make its direct children equal height, by removing margin CSS `margin: auto 0.5% 1% auto;` will resolve the issue. The issue with your margin CSS is `auto` value will align the `flex` item to vertically center, no wonder you don't get equal height.

Let me know if you need some more help,

Comment: In case you don't want to use `box-sizing`, you have to re-calculate the `width` and `padding` to make it even, usually it's a good practice to put it in the beginning of your CSS to reset this property, this will save your CSS hours

Comment: The explanation is great information for me. I just want to know If I have to give the space between each li then ? should I use margin-right?

Comment: This answer is correct for me with a good explanation. Thanks for the help @Duc

Comment: sure thing you can apply a gap between columns, but that would take a bit more CSS to apply (negative margin is the key word if you're curious), I'll get back to this later

Comment: here's the example for gap between columns, we need to modify a bit in HTML structure and also with CSS. But the takeaway point here is to make a negative margin and add a padding value equal to the `negative margin` you've added. E.g you want a `24px` gap between each columns, that means each one will need `12px` on each side => `margin-left` and `margin-right` will be `-12px`, while the column will have a `12px` padding. This is the way Bootstrap and also Foundation grid system works. Link demo: https://codepen.io/DieByMacro/pen/QXaKbb

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.List {
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: auto;
}

.List ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.List ul li {
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 12px 0px #EBE8E8;
  border-radius: 03px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0 10px;
  flex: 1 0 19%;
  max-width: 19%;
}
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/nalindobhal/pen/WqdNzq)

Comment: equal height issue resolved but I have to display four li tag in one row and the rest of the display below.

Comment: what do you mean by "the rest of the display below", does that mean from the 5th one the column will span full width or just take its own width ?

Comment: @DucHong, No, I am displaying the list. All the li tag with equal width. I have to display the first four li in one row. I mean four columns and reset of the the li display in second row of the column.

Comment: @DucHong, I added my expected output in the question

Comment: @questionbank I have edited my answer as per the given css. please check

Comment: @NalinDobhal, Yes, your answer is also working. Thanks for the help. Upvote from my side.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost right but needs some enhancement...You have to remove add display flex property on ul and flex warp property also...flex wrap automatically break the element according to view port..And there is no need to add margin in li..

CSS:

```css
.List ul {
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: flex-start;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .List ul li {
      width: 20%;
        padding: 20px;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 12px 0px #EBE8E8;
        border-radius: 03px;
        background-color: #fff;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
```

Comment: Your answer is also working for me. Thanks for the help. Upvote from my side.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know that you want only 4 columns in a row, set the width of each li element to `25%`. But considering that you're applying padding and margins as well, reduce the width of the `li`s by the amount of padding and margin you're giving.

*Also, try to be consistent in using units of values, such as %, px, em, etc. Mixing and matching these in the same element can give unexpected results.*

So here, setting the padding to be 1% on each side, and margin to be 0.5% and 1% on the right and left respectively will take up a total of 3.5% of total width for each `li`. So just set the width to something less than 21.5% and you'll get 4 elements per row.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.List {
  /*max-width: 1140px;*/
  margin: auto;
}

.List ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.List ul li {
  width: 21.5%;
  padding: 1%;;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 12px 0px #EBE8E8;
  border-radius: 03px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: auto 0.5% 1% auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="List">
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo sociis natoque
    </li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean </li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque
    </li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo sociis natoque
    </li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean </li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo sociis natoque
    </li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque
    </li>


  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Using your code, I am getting in  4 columns  what about the equal height?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using `display: flex;` for this you don't need to give minimum height as well. And also layout is easy to manage and make it responsive.

```css
.cstm-row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}
.cstm-column {
    flex: 1;
}
.orange-column {
    background-color: #ffc04d;
}
.blue-column {
    background-color: #4d4dff;
}
.green-column {
    background-color: #00ffc0;
}
.cstm-row .cstm-column:first-child {
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.cstm-row .cstm-column {
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.cstm-row .cstm-column:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.cstm-row li {
    flex: 1;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.cstm-row li:first-child {
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.cstm-row li {
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.cstm-row li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="cstm-row">
    <li class="orange-column">
        <p>The passage experienced a surge in popularity during the 1960s when Letraset used it on their dry-transfer sheets, and again during the 90s as desktop publishers bundled the text with their software. Today it's seen all around the web; on templates, websites, and stock designs. Use our generator to get your own, or read on for the authoritative history of lorem ipsum.</p>
    </li>
    <li class="blue-column">
        <p>Until recently, the prevailing view assumed lorem ipsum was born as a nonsense text.</p>
    </li>
    <li class="green-column">
        <p>Until recently, the prevailing view assumed lorem ipsum was born as a nonsense text.</p>
    </li>
    <li class="blue-column">
        <p>Until recently, the prevailing view assumed lorem ipsum was born as a nonsense text.</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```